# HTTP header for indicating originating server behind load balancer

Tags: http

For debugging purposes, we would like to configure our pool of load balanced web servers to output an HTTP header identifying the "true" server which served the request. However, we don't know what header name this should be! Is there any pre-existing header for this? Do you have a favorite?

Answer (score 19):

AFAIK there isn't a formal standard for this. What I've seen is:

- A custom HTTP header. It's really your choice as long as you [stay in the X- namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810915/is-safe-to-use-x-header-in-a-http-response). For me personally `X-Backend-Server` is descriptive, and [it seems popular](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=x%20backend%20server%20header).
- Writing the backend server ID into an HTML comment at the end of the content body.

**Update: I found this [survey](http://www.shodanhq.com/research/infodisc/report)** of HTTP headers in the wild from 2011. My suggestion `X-Backend-Server` is number 119, while `X-Server-Name`  [is number 56 on the list](http://www.shodanhq.com/research/infodisc/headers?page=2). So I'd say `X-Server-Name` seems the most common header for this.

Comment: Note that the X- prefix was deprecated: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648

Comment: @Edward Z. Yang: Good comment. From that RFC, section 1, bullet 4: "Makes no recommendation as to whether existing "X-" parameters ought to remain in use or be migrated [...]". Absent any newer implementations (that I don't know of) I would personally stick with X-Backend-Server or a similar "X-" header. :-)

Comment: The real point is that regardless of whether the "X-" headers are official, deprecated or anything else, they won't break anything and are very useful for purposes such as the one being asked about here. In short, it's perfectly fine to use them.

Comment: It looks like X-Served-By is actually used more as of today, according to that report.

Comment: Links broken...